# javascript refer to object by string google marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My application allows users to search for venues and plot those results on a google map.

what I want to do is when a user mouseovers an item in the results list it opens the corresponding markers info window. When i add the markers I append the record it to the marker name. So all my markers are called marker_xx where xx is the record ID.

I am able to interact with a marker and send a click to it using the following code:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker_40, "click");
```

but if I trying dynamically generate the name using the follow two lines it does not work

```
    var name = "marker_" + markerIdentifier;
    google.maps.event.trigger(name, "click");
```

so I guess i need to get the actual 'marker_object' to send in to the google function. But I don't know how to do this.

here is my function in full markerIdentifier is an id that match a record in the results list and there will be a matching marker on the map.

```
function MarkerZoomTo(markerIdentifier) {


    var name = "marker_" + markerIdentifier;

    google.maps.event.trigger(name, "click");

    google.maps.event.trigger(marker_40, "click");
```

}

any hints would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of your code, it looks like `marker_40` exists in the global namespace.

That being said, you should be able to access it using

```
var marker = window['marker_' + markerIdentifier];
```

However, I suggest that you save your markers in an array and fetch the one that you need from it.

Comment: Np, but I suggest that you don't pollute `window` with all your markers. Do you have them in an array?

Comment: Not at the moment I am writing the application in codeigntier and using the biostall google maps library, with generates the maps code. I will put it on the todo list to modify it to hold them in an array